# Angular Bootstrap Tabs Causing Strange Wrapping

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular Bootstrap UI tabset directive and having some trouble with strange CSS.  Here's my HTML, [and also a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GeQY8YTPFrd9U9p1sHNz?p=preview).  Why is the div#content wrapping?  How to I make it appear directly below the tabs where it belongs?

```
<div id="left">
  floating left div with static height and width
</div>

<div id="right">
  <div>standard div with width=100%.  presence of tabs is screwing up content below them</div>
  <tabset>
    <tab>
      <tab-heading>Tab 1</tab-heading>
    </tab>
    <tab>
      <tab-heading>Tab 2</tab-heading>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
  <div id="content">
    Why is this wrapping below???
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** It looks like the CSS class "nav" has a rule ".nav:after { clear:both; }" which is clearing the left float and causing the problem.  But I don't know how to fix this still.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a style of display: inline-block on the tabset element seems to fix the problem.